# sdl 2 with visual studio 2013 ( simple example doesn't work keep crashing)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sdl-2

I was compiling SDL2 with Visual Studio 2010 without any troubles. I've decided to upgrade visual studio to 2013. My simple example doesn't run and keep showing me this message

[image]

This is what I've done

My project folder looks like

```
main.cpp 
SDL2.dll ( from F:xxx\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86
```

CMD is

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC> cl /?
    Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Compiling from cmd

```
cl /EHsc /MD  main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I F:\C++_Libraries\SDL2\SDL2-2.0.3\include /link /LIBPATH:F:\C++_Libraries\SDL2\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86 SDL2.lib SDL2main.lib /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

    // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );

    // Check that the window was successfully made
    if (window == NULL) {
        // In the event that the window could not be made...
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // The window is open: enter program loop (see SDL_PollEvent)

    SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example

    // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be due to the fact that you *probably* didn't recompile your dll with the 2013 toolset.

Comment: I just downloaded them from the SDL2 website. How can I recompile them with 2013? There is nothing in their website regarding this matter.

Comment: Download the [source](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). compile it using VS2013. done!

Comment: The dlls are provided in the source folder. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You need to compile SDL2 yourself if you can't find a precompiled 2013 version online. Did you compile it already?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Would you please shed some light.

Comment: @CroCo In SDL2\VisualC\ you will find the project files. Just open the .sln and build it.

Comment: I've run .sln (building the entire solution) this is what I got `========== Build: 2 succeeded, 19 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: thank you so much. This definitely will solve the problem but how you did manage to find `#include <dxsdkver.h>`. This header is missing in my case. In here http://frost.ics.uci.edu/ics161/Homework1.pdf  they suggested to comment out the `#include <dxsdkver.h>`. Is this right?

Comment: @CroCo luckily, I've got one on my PC. But I believe [commenting out its references should be alright](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca03a834-1108-4767-b19c-773cfd8a47e5/is-dxsdkverh-header-file-missing-from-the-windows-sdk-as-of-8-and-81?forum=windowssdk). Btw. did it solve you problem? If so, please consider accepting the answer.